# Help identifying these comics

Tags: story-identification, character-identification, webcomics

[image]
<sub>Source: http://ohumanstar.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/OHS-fanart-by-kgschmidt.jpg</sub>

from the left:

1)

2) Luna? (if so from everblue)

3)

4)Vattu from "Vattu" by Evan Dahm

5)charlie from "As the Crow Flies" by Melanie Gillman

6)Sandra from "Zebra Girl" by Joe England

7)Sulla from "O Human Star" by Blue Delliquanti

8)______ from "Kill Six Billion Demons" by Abbadon

Who are the other characters and what comics do they come from?

Comment: It seems like the stack will be neater if any more incomplete answers are left as comments. is there an etiquette to it in this stack?

Comment: I think what usually happens with these kinds of questions is that someone creates a community answer, and then if someone knows a specific character, they can chip in and edit that character into the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Searching the artist I found it pretty easily :

From Left to Right:

- Hero, from Modmad’s The Property of Hate,
- Luna, from Blue-Ten’s Everblue,
- Credenza, from H.L. DeVera’s  Archipelago,
- Vattu, the titular character of Evan Dahm’s Vattu,
- Charlie, from Melanie Gillman’s As the Crow Flies,
- Zandra, from Joe England’s Zebra Girl,
- Sulla, from O Human Star,
- Allison, from Abbadon’s Kill Six Billion Demons.

Source:
http://blue-ten.tumblr.com/post/86391542820/kgschmidt-i-went-down-my-webcomics-bookmark

Answer (score 2):

I recognise one of them. Zandra/Sandra from "Zebra Girl" (zebragirl.thecomicseries.com, zebragirl.net) is the one with the tail, hooves and three eyes. (so third from right.)

Answer (score 1):

The image on the far right is from the webcomic "[Kill Six Billion Demons](https://killsixbilliondemons.com)".